# Filling Dataframe with data from For-Loop

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to fill an DataFrame with every second word from another element, but that doesn't work:

```
import pandas as pd

   
output[0] = "Word 1"
output[2] = "Word 2"
output[4] = "Word 3"

tab = pd.DataFrame(index=5, columns=1)
tab = tab.fillna(0)
f=0
for i in range(1,len(output),2):
    tab[f]=output[i]
    f=f+1
    print(output[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear what you are trying to achieve, please review [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question

But going out on a limb here, suppose you have a list `output`:

```
output = [f'Word {n}' for n in range(10)]
print(output)
```

that looks like this:

```
['Word 0', 'Word 1', 'Word 2', 'Word 3', 'Word 4', 'Word 5', 'Word 6', 'Word 7', 'Word 8', 'Word 9']
```

then you can create a dataframe from every second element of this list using the slicing operator for lists:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(output[::2])
df
```

we get

```
    0
0   Word 0
1   Word 2
2   Word 4
3   Word 6
4   Word 8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {'Words': output}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df = df.iloc[::2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. And it´s true, my question wasn't really precise.

I split a string and got an element with different words. But just every second row contains a word that i need, the other rows contains just useless data.

So the output file looks like this:

```
output[0]: lkjlajsflkjaf
output[1]: Banana
output[2]: lksjdflkjsdfljk
output[3]: Dog
```

I want to filter out every second word to get a dataframe with just the words I need, in this case:

```
tab[0]: Banana
tab[1]: Dog
```

Comment: thanks for clarifications. But you should edit your original question rather than add answers that clarify your question, if that  makes sense. All this is well covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Anyways, seems like the answers you got should work for your use case -- if they do not please provide feedback, and if they do, pls mark them [accordingly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)